# Creating a data frame from nrow results of different vectors/data frames

Tags: r

I have some vectors in different data.frames. I want to count the number of observations of each vectors and make a list out of it. The first column should be the data frame names and the second columns should be the number of observations in each data frame. A minimal example could be,

```
x <- c(1, 3, 4, 5, 6)
x1 <- data.frame(x)
y <- c(3, 9)
y1 <- data.frame(y)
z <- c(23, 43, 23, 12, 1, 3, 7,8,9)
z1 <- data.frame(z)

a <- nrow(x1)
b <- nrow(y1)
c <- nrow(z1)

d <- c(a, b, c)
e <- data.frame(d)
e
```

The output e looks like this,

```
> e
  d
1 5
2 2
3 9
```

However, I want that in this way,

```
>  e
  df.name nobs
1      x1    5
2      y1    2
3      z1    9
```

Any help would be greately appreciated.

Comment: Where did you find `x2` and `x3`? - You also have a typo at `d` (`data.framec`). Also you are doing everything manually, so add the names manually...i.e. `setNames(c(a, b, c), c('x1', 'y1', 'z1'))`

Comment: Yes. It's a typo. Fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
x <- c(1, 3, 4, 5, 6)
x1 <- data.frame(x)
y <- c(3, 9)
y1 <- data.frame(y)
z <- c(23, 43, 23, 12, 1, 3, 7,8,9)
z1 <- data.frame(z)

library(purrr)
targlist <- list(x1,y1,z1)
data.frame(
    names=unlist(map(targlist,names)),
    nobs=unlist(map(targlist,nrow))
)
```

If there's more than one col `names` is going to misbehave. Maybe you want `names=paste0("x",1:length(targlist))` instead. But this was fun for your example.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `base R`

```
stack(lapply(mget(c("x1", "y1", "z1")), nrow))[2:1]
```